# Spring annotations getting values from application.properties

Tags: java, spring-mvc, properties, spring-boot

I want to set values from my application.properties into employees, publicholidays and name field from the application.properties. However, upon running the application, the values are not injected into the field. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
package hello.entities;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import java.util.*;

@Component
public class SessionShift{
    String day;
    String month;
    String year;

    @Value("#{'${my.list.of.employees}'.split(',')}") 
    private List<String> employees;

    @Value("#{'${my.list.of.PH}'.split(',')}") 
    private List<String> publicholidays;

    @Value("${my.name}") 
    private String name;

    public List getEmployees(){
        System.out.println("GETTING EMPLOYEES");
        return this.employees;
    }

    public List getPublicholidays(){
        System.out.println("GETTING PH");
        return this.publicholidays;
    }


    public String getName(){
        System.out.println("GETTING NAME");
        return this.name;
    }


    public void setEmployees(List employees){
        System.out.println("SETTING EMPLOYEES");
        this.employees = employees;
    }

    public void setPublicholidays(List<String> publicholidays){
        System.out.println("SETTING PH");
        this.publicholidays = publicholidays;
    }


    public void setName(String name){
        System.out.println("SETTING NAME");
         this.name = name;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
myname = {name}
server.port=8186
error.whitelabel.enabled=false
my.list.of.employees=test1,test2
my.list.of.PH=08/04/2016
my.name = manish
```

Comment: how are you instantiating this? These will only work if it is autowired (which is the mistake I have used in the past to use `new`

Comment: what version of Spring do you use? 'Cos there might be different solutions for different version of Spring. 
Anyway, you can try to get it like     
`private List<String> employees;
@Autowired
    public void setEmployeesList(@Value("${my.list.of.employees}") final String strs) {
        employees= Arrays.asList(strs.split(","));
    }`

Comment: Similar to the first comment the way in which you instantiate it matters.  If you just do a "new" operation then Spring cannot inject.  You need to use the application context to get a bean or include this as an autowired field in a different class.  Please edit your question to show how it is used.